# Using multiple forms and passing information between them

Tags: android

I've been messing around with Android development.

I made a simple form that has two fields for numbers, and when you press the Calculate button, it multiplies them.

What I would like to do is when I press Calculate to open another form, and pass that multiplied number to it to display it.

I'm really not sure how to do this though, the whole xml and findViewById thing is pretty different from what I've done before. When I started the project in Eclipse, the main.xml and strings.xml was created for me.

I tried googling around but I just find tutorials using one form

Could someone point me to a good tutorial for this, or explain how to create a new form, create/open it, and pass some information to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start a new Activity (what you're calling Form), you need to create an intent. To pass data to that activity, you can bind "extras" into the intent:

```
Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("someuniquename","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new activity, you can retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
String value = extras.getString("someuniquename");
}
```

Comment: thanks, that was really simple! I think I just need to get my head around the idea of activities and intents, I'm kind of used to just creating forms

Answer (score 1):

As your UI is simple (but I also use it for more complex ones), you could also try `ViewFlipper`, it contains several forms (Views) and as you stay in the same `Activity` (so the same class) you do not need to worry about passing information between them they are all accessible.

http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-view-flipper-in-android.html

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example